# How can I implement PKCE Auth with SpotifyAPI-NET and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, spotify

In the SpotifyAPI-NET [documentation](https://johnnycrazy.github.io/SpotifyAPI-NET/docs/pkce/), it says that PCKE is the best version for desktop apps so I wanted to with this auth method. But it says I need to use a callback function like

```
// This method should be called from your web-server when the user visits "http://localhost:5000/callback"
public Task GetCallback(string code)
{
  // Note that we use the verifier calculated above!
  var initialResponse = await new OAuthClient().RequestToken(
    new PKCETokenRequest("ClientId", code, "http://localhost:5000", verifier)
  );

  var spotify = new SpotifyClient(initialResponse.AccessToken);
  // Also important for later: response.RefreshToken
}
```

I don't know how to implement a callback in c#, Is there any way to implement it or should I use a different method for authentication or what should I use?

Answer (score 1):

so I found an answer

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:5000/callback");
listener.Start();
while (true)
{
    var context = listener.GetContext();
    if(context != null)
    {  
        // This is the code from Spotify API
        var codeToRetrieve = context.Request.QueryString["code"];
        await GetCallback(codeToRetrieve);
        break;
    }
  
}
listener.Stop();
```

but later GetCallback function would get me the error `SpotifyAPI.Web.APIException: 'invalid_grant'`
and in the end, I realized that I needed to use the same URL in the callback and request so I made this

```
public const string CallbackURL = "http://localhost:5000/callback/";
public async Task GetCallback(string code)
{
    var initialResponse = await new OAuthClient().RequestToken(
            new PKCETokenRequest("ClientId", code, new System.Uri(CallbackURL), verifier)
    ); 
    var spotify = new SpotifyClient(initialResponse.AccessToken);
    var user = await spotify.UserProfile.Current();
    Debug.WriteLine(user.DisplayName);
}
public async Task StartServer()
{  
    HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
    listener.Prefixes.Add(CallbackURL);
    listener.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        var context = listener.GetContext();
        if(context != null)
        {  
            // This is the code from Spotify API
            var codeToRetrieve = context.Request.QueryString["code"];
            await GetCallback(codeToRetrieve);
            break;
        }

    }
    listener.Stop();
}
```